# subprocess or threads for checking pings to a server?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, ping

I've never used multithreaded processes before or tried to make them and I'm a noob to coding subprocesses but I understand what forking is conceptually and it isn't that hard to understand per se.

What I'm trying to do is keep track of ping spikes on network. Basically, I would run `ping 1.2.3.4` in a subprocess and check the output of it in the main thread, then process that output. However, the code as of now looks like this:

```
def run_background_ping():
    background_ping=subprocess.Popen(args)
    with background_ping.stdout:
        for line in iter(background_ping.stdout.readline)
            process(line)
```

which means that I'm still running the ping function in a subprocess running on the main thread. What that means practically is that I see the output of the ping constantly, which I don't think I should be. in which case, how do i get this operation to run in the background and constantly poll it while some other things are happening? What i want is this

```
def ping_subprocess()
    ping the server in a subprocess
    return a string whenever there is output

def read_ping_subprocess_output()
    current_ping = poll(ping_subprocess.output)
    eval(current_ping)

ping_subprocess()
read_ping_subprocess_output() # <-- how do i get to this code
```

but the problem is that the `ping_subprocess()` method will wait until the output of the process finishes, which will technically never happen since the ping process runs indefinitely and would only be stopped if i purposefully give it some other signal which i plan on coding in later.

How do I make it such that the subprocess method will return once the process starts instead of waiting for it to end so that I can read its output? I'm sure another option is to constantly append the output of the ping function into a file (within reason) and read that file simultaneously with another program, but I'm not sure if that's the best idea.

So in terms of threads (if this is needed) how would this go? I've heard that mixing threads and subprocesses is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm presuming you're on a LAN, otherwise you probably shouldn't be doing this at all (or trusting the results, for that matter).  That being said, this would be FAR easier if you just *sent* the actual echo request in python (using scapy or dpkt/pcap or a bunch of other options), instead of calling out to the ping command and trying to parse output.

Comment: Is this a unixy system or windows?

Comment: this is a unix system. @NickBastin i've never used scapy but i could try to learn that - for now this is just for my edification. I'm on lan and this process is going to be running from virtual machines at the end for sure so that the results will be a little more accurate. what would you recommend?